# How to set nodejs windows service as high priority

Tags: node.js, windows-services, pm2

I have a node server and script that runs as a windows service using https://github.com/jon-hall/pm2-windows-service and pm2.

The server is time sensitive and I am seeing situations where the hardware is hitting 100% CPU usage and the script timing goes off, sometimes several minutes off.

I want to mitigate this by setting the service to high priority.  How can I do that?

I have found some solutions involving VBScript https://serverfault.com/questions/179161/change-windows-service-priority, but is there a pm2 or node way of setting the service or elevating itself after it runs?

Also, please comment if I posted this on wrong site.  It's a bit grey since it's both a server problem and a programming problem.

Comment: At first I was like "you were able to get pm2 to work for you on windows?!"  I think I had an issue where I wasn't running a .js script but I needed to run an npm command and everything fell off a cliff from there

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you write a program that runs window's "start /high yourservice.exe", but that would involve a lot of going in depth of pm2-windows-service I think.  You could probably just call node `exec` on windows using something like https://superuser.com/questions/620724/changing-windows-process-priority-via-command-line

Comment: It looks like the service just shows up as node.exe, 6 of them.  One appears to be pm2\lib\ProcessContainerFork.  That seems to be the busiest one.  So I guess I could just boost them all?

Comment: I'd probably read up on windows priority and what it does. I feel like I've read before that it shouldn't really be necessary to change, but I could be wrong

Comment: @CodyG. It worked, I added it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do it using this code and the end of my load up process.

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');
exec('wmic process where "ProcessId=' + process.pid + '" CALL setpriority 256');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`os.setPriority`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#ossetprioritypid-priority):

```js
import os from 'node:os';
os.setPriority(process.pid, os.constants.priority.PRIORITY_HIGHEST);
```